# Trying to find name of TFS DB Table containing custom field data

Tags: database, tfs

I have a quick question, what is the name of the TFS 2010 database table that contains values for any custom fields.

I did a query against the TFS_Warehouse DB and the dbo.DimWorkItem table. However, I cannot find any of my custom work item fields under this table.

Can someone point me to the correct TFS 2010 table containing the custom field data? When I worked with Quality Center, the tables were pretty well defined so it was easy to do backend DB queries. TFS does not seem that intuitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look, 
you need to go to your collection database, and to check a table called something like Fields.
there, you will find the new field properties and the type as well.

you can change the type to string and to be reportable.

go to the table of the WORKITEMLATEST, and check the field- you can see the name of the field like what was mentioned in the FIELDS table,.

open your work item normally, edit that field information, click save...

you can see your data updated in the WORKITEMLATEST table

BUT...
the problem is the STRING type is limited... I tried to add more text.. it keep telling me that number of character is over limit !

Comment: In TFS 2017 this can be found in the view vw_denorm_WorkItemCustomLatest

Answer (score 2):

you have to add "reportable" to field definition.

Example - FIELD name="Scope" refname="xxx.Scope" type="String" reportable="dimension"

Wait few minutes and you'll see field in warehouse DB

Comment: Thank you, I do have a follow up question. The reportable setting has to be placed within the work item XML. Can this also be done through the UI? There is an option to add "reportable" when opening the work item through TFS power tools. In addition, am I looking at the correct table within the TFS_Warehouse DB?
EDIT: Yes that is the correct DB Table and it's working as described. Thank you!